# How to Detect Touch Screen users?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using an exit intent popup in my website.

Naturally, it will work only for desktop users, as touch screen users do not have a mouse that the script can follow.

Therefore, for those touch screen users, I would like to trigger the same pop up after several seconds of browsing my website.

How can I do this?

I don't mind if it is PHP or Javascript / Jquery

Comment: that sounds like mega-annoying functionality

Comment: You cannot reliably differentiate between pure touch screen users or people with touch screens and a mouse and keyboard (e.g. as it's the case in some hybrid laptops). If you're content with just checking if a touch screen is there then Modernizr has touch detection.

Comment: @apokryfos I would be good with a general way then to detected iphone, ipad, and android devices.

Comment: Check http://mobiledetect.net/ for a PHP solution.

Comment: @apokryfos why did you delete your answer? I didn't had a chance to go through it yet.

Comment: @rockyraw it was getting downvoted so I assumed it wasn't what you needed. I brought it back.

Comment: can't I simply look for the word `mobile` in the user agent?